# How redirect action with all params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have action in controller Statistic

```
     public ViewResult Index(string userName, GridSortOptions gridSortOptions, int? page, DateTime? dateTimeFrom, DateTime? dateTimeTo)
            {
    ..
}
```

I create partial view _FromToDateViewPage.cshtml

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepickerFrom").datepicker();
        $("#datepickerTo").datepicker();
    });
</script>



<div class="date_box">

<p><span>Date From: <input type="text" id="datepickerFrom"></span><span>Date To: <input type="text" id="datepickerTo"></span></p>
@Html.RouteLink("Filter", new { Controller = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue, Action = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue, dateTimeFrom = DateTime.Now })

</div><!-- Date (From To) Picker Box -->
```

I need a filter button that sends the current effect that all options were. And + dateTimeFrom and dateTimeTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you have to use a submit button and not a link.

```
<form>

<input type="hidden" name="page" value="@ViewBag.page">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="@ViewBag.username">
<!-- deserialize the gridSortOptions -->
<input type="hidden" name="gridSortOptions_field" value="@ViewBag.gridSortOptions_field">
<input type="hidden" name="gridSortOptions_field" value="@ViewBag.gridSortOptions_direction">

<!-- add the value attribute and set it's value to datepickerFrom stored in viewBag -->
Date From: <input type="text" id="datepickerFrom" name="datepickerFrom"  value="@ViewBag.datepickerFrom">

<!-- add the value attribute and set it's value to datepickerTostored in viewBag -->
Date To: <input type="text" id="datepickerTo" name="datepickerTo" value="@ViewBag.datepickerTo">

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: and how to pass parameters ? (string userName, GridSortOptions gridSortOptions, int? page)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: first 4 input I do not need me to different pages in different settings